# In Rymdkapsel, does extractor efficiency boost speed or quantity?

Tags: rymdkapsel

The top right monolith boosts extraction efficiency.

What does this mean exactly? Speed? Quantity? Both?

Comment: Thanks for re-tagging, I don't have the rep and had to choose something. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not improve speed, as far as I have tested. It increases the amount of minerals you can get from one field.